# how to copy local directory with files to remote server talend

Tags: talend

in Talend(data integration) i am trying to copy local directory to remote directory but when i am running the job only i can copy files but not folders from directory.please help me with this job.

In my talend job i am using local connection and remote connection components->
tfilelist->tfileproperties(to store path and name in one table)->tmssqlinput(extracting path from last table)->iteration-> tssh(if directory s not available then create)->finally sending it to tftpput to connect and copy to remote directory.

when i am storing in one table using tfileproperties in that for files it will generate some size but when folder s coming the size will be zero,using this condition m creating the directory using tssh component but unable to create folders,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get an error message?

I believe the output of the TMSSqlInput should be a row based, rather than iteration.  That might be the source of the problem.

[tMSqlInput docs](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tMSSqlInput)

> tMSSqlInput executes a DB query with a strictly defined order which
>   must correspond to the schema definition. Then it passes on the field
>   list to the next component via a Main row link.

Comment: Hi,As you mentioned i have used tmssqlinput row based only and then from tjavarow i have iterated to get all files and folders.I am able to copy all files to server and job is working fine with no errors but my question is to copy folders from local to server with files present in the folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a not a single component which does all of that. Depending on the need and how comfortable you are in Java,  you could leverage the jsch  library to connect, make directories, and push files over.

Alternatively, you could create a zip or tar of the directory and its subfolders w/ files. Then, use tSFTP to transfer the files.  Then, use tSsh to connect again and untar / unzip the file, containing subfolders and files.